# I can't download tflite-model-maker or get tflite model

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, text-classification, tflite

I need a neural network to classify text into sentimentality, but I need it in the .tflite format, since this is the format that Android Studio and android in general accepts.
I'm new to neural networks and python, but as I understand it after reading the tensorflow and google guides, you can solve this problem in two ways: either make a model and then convert it, or initially make it using tflite-model-maker

I tried saving my neural networks and converting them to .tflite, but I could only convert one model normally (I did several for the test) and android studio says that this is not a tflite model, although the extension is like this.

When I tried to download the tflite-model-maker module via google colab, there was an endless download and, as I understood, this is because this module requires python 3.9.
After that, I downloaded VS Code and python 3.9 and tried to download there, but I had a lot of problems, about the conflict between numpy, pandas, protobuff, tensorflow_datasets and the like, as well as the lack of array_record and "resource", and even after fixing some More and more problems are popping up.

I tried it through jupyter notebook, but I couldn't find tflite-model-maker there

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker import configs
from tflite_model_maker import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import text_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.text_classifier import DataLoader

assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```

These are the dependencies that I need, and which are not described in the tensorflow documentation
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker/text_classification
A link to google colab is given, but as I said, I have endless loading

Comment: According to [here](https://pypi.org/project/tflite-model-maker/) and following use of the magic install commands within running `.ipynb` files, you should be able to install `tflite-model-maker` by making a new cell in the Jupyter notebook where you are working and running `%pip install tflite-model-maker`. Note the magic command at the start of the install command. Not following all your mentions of "download the tflite-model-maker" in the title and post text otherwise. You run the install command & it retrieves it, assuming you have an actual UNBLOCKED internet connection, and installs it.

Comment: <continued> That is only for actual Jupyter and not Google Colab. Google Colab is highly modified version of very old Jupyter and a lot of conveniences of modern Jupyter, such as [the magic install commands](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) that insure the installations occur in the proper environment, are not present in it. (The exclamation point in place of the magic symbol should work though because Google set it up so it will work. Stick with magic variation in true Jupyter for a better experience.)